# Cannot upload certain type in Drive using Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am trying to update some files in my drive using the following piece of code

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload, MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
import io
import pandas as pd

PATH_FOLDER = './'

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scopes)

http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
drive = build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

def upload_file(file_name):
    """ This function purpose is to find
    a file in the drive having the same name as the 
    file_name parameter then uploads a new version 
    using the local file having the same name
    param:
    file_name(str) : name of the file to update in drive (also
    name of the local file to use as new version)
    """ 
    files = drive.files().list().execute()['files']
    for file in files:
        if file['name'] == file_name:
            file_id = file['id']
            break
    file_metadata = {
    'name': file_name,
    'mimeType': file['mimeType']
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload(PATH_FOLDER + file_name, mimetype=file['mimeType'], resumable=True)
    drive.files().update(
    fileId=file_id,
    body=file_metadata, 
    media_body=media, 
    ).execute()
```

When I try to upload certain file type (pkl, csv):

```
upload_file('universe.pkl')
upload_file('list.csv')
```

the code runs without any error but the files do not change in my drive
whereas when I apply the same function for a different type (xlsx, txt):

```
upload_file('info.xlsx')
upload_file('test.txt')
```

it works fine and my files get updated. Did anyone face the same problem? and if so what was the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your issue only with the function `upload_file?`

Comment: Yes inly with the upload_file function. I tried also drive.files().create and it does not work also for the same extensions.

Comment: I suggest removing the code that is unnecessary for your question. See [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In the following line of your `upload_file` function you have hard-coded the mime-type:

> `media = MediaFileUpload(PATH_FOLDER + file_name, mimetype='text/csv', resumable=True)`

Make sure that the mime-type you specify on `file-metadata` equals the one in `media`

Comment: Yes, you're right. But even when I keep the same mime type as the old version of files with the non standard extensions (csv, pkl), nothing changes in Drive. I updated the question to avoid confusion about this specific problem.

Comment: Please break down your question to a single issue, with steps to reproduce and the expected vs. actual behavior. Clarify what you are trying to do. (eg. Upload a single file "name.ext" from local to Drive)

Comment: I edited a bit but I'm not sure if it's more understandable now.

Comment: I was able to upload and update both .csv and .pkl (mimetype="application/octet-stream") without problems. Everytime I run the code, a new version of the file is created.